# How do I inject creds for dblink? Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am using `dblink` with Postgres 12 to pull data from a remote database and inject it into a local environment. I am using `dblink`, bc it allows me to use a `where` clause to filter the data however I need to filter it. I am not wanting to check in my creds and I am also wanting to be able to remotely access different db's. I cannot find a way to do this with `dblink`. Here is the command that I am running:

```
insert into company(company_id, name, matching_regex)
    (select company.*
     from dblink(
             'dbname=test host=test.amazonaws.com port=5432 user=test password=password',
             'select company_id, name, matching_regex from company'
         ) AS company(company_id bigint, name varchar(100), matching_regex varchar(200)));
```

I have tried using [`.pgpass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/libpq-pgpass.html) (a file with the creds embedded), but `dblink` is not able to read it for some reason. Can someone give an example of how to inject the creds, or another way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Postgres version? Define what '.pgpass, but haven't been able to make it work' means?  Add this information as update to your question. Why not use [postgres-fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html)?

Comment: Does it help you ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41486198/postgresql-9-5-hide-password-from-dblink-connection

Comment: What about a foreign table using the extension postgres_fdw? Then you can store the credentials in the user mapping.